# Operand should contain 1 column(s) on simple insert

Tags: mysql, sql

```
insert into A (c,d) 
(select (c,d) 
from B)
```

Both, Table A and B have columns c and d. Still, I get `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put extra parentheses around the things you SELECT.

```
insert into A (c,d) 
(select c, d
from B)
```

Comment: Plus you don't put parentheses around the select itself.

Comment: Parentheses around the whole select make no difference (although you can remove them) but it really should work without parentheses around the fields you select. (At least my tests do)
If it doesn't, can you show the real query? The problem might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
insert into A (c,d) 
select c,d
from B
```